# Javascript package vs. wrapper for another language

Tags: javascript, php, ruby-on-rails

I want to display a chart with backend code in PHP or Ruby. There are lots of javascript packages for that job and some wrapper package in PHP. Both do the same task, but in different language.

1. I can give my frontend an API, then get things done by a JS charting library.
2. I can give data to that wrapper package (composer/ruby gem), then get things done by PHP.

Which one is the best practice, and why?

Comment: That's a matter of taste.... normally JS would be the better choice, since it is handled clientside, which makes it more interactive. If you pull data from a PHP / Ruby API, you can even make updates in realtime, without requiring page reloads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would go for a frontend library (chartjs, d3js...) for a few reasons:

1. Only one implementation
2. No page reload

**Only one implementation**

This separation of concerns will allow you to change your backend implementation at any time. You could have at some point php and ruby code running simultaneously that your frontend won't break the established contract.

**No page reload**

Elaborating in an answer, having the frontend doing the heavy lifting have some benefits, one of them is AJAX. If you have a chart that requires real time information being displayed (say, on a second basis) then you'd just throttle / debounce every some time interval calls to your API.

Usually you want as many decouple components when architecting a system.